# Meaning of numbers in UK Parliament Sessional Papers

Tags: united-kingdom, legal-history

I have a (scan of) [an 1858 volume](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/002240203) of papers drawn from Sessional Papers of the British Parliament.

These appear to be [Command Papers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_paper), which, according to various [sources](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~deh25/post/Timeline_files/UK-Parliamentary_Papers.html), were numbered [1] to [4222] over the period 1833–1869. The Command Paper numbers (in 1857/8, in the low 2000s) do not appear in the papers, but they do appear in the index: e.g. [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=a6hbAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA2-PA23#v=snippet&q=naval&f=false) and [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EKpbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA54#v=onepage&q=naval&f=false).

All the sections in the volume have numbers printed on the first page at the bottom left. Sometimes, this is the sessional paper number, eg. "[155—Sess 2](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015027808826&view=1up&seq=679)" (which agrees with the index).

But, sometimes, the number is a mystery to me. The section on [page 345](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015027808826&view=1up&seq=345) is numbered "[120]", which does not correspond to paper 120 in either 1857 session ([1st](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=a6hbAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PR20#v=onepage&f=false), [2nd](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EKpbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PR34#v=onepage&f=false)) - this section is, in fact Command Paper [2166], [listed in the index](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=a6hbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PR27#v=onepage&f=false) as coming from the 1857 1st Session, Volume XII., page 579. It seems this number is not a sessional paper number, command paper number or page number.

So, what *does* [120] mean in his context?

Comment: [110] appears at the bottom of p9. Could be a clue?

Comment: That page is another command paper [2163], which was originally Vol XII, page 51. Non-command sessional paper 110 was about Flogging in the Army. Page 241 has [194], and so on. Again, the connection is not clear to me.